# Marklogic performance difference for queries within same database

Tags: marklogic

I have a 28770 document database, filled with 3 kinds of XML documents. For 2 out of 3 rootelements, count(//rootelementname) is very fast (0.01sec). However, a count query on the third root element is extremely slow (17sec). I was wondering why.

The problematic root element is called SGDTEKST. If I enter:

```
count(//SGDTEKST), xdmp:query-meters()
```

then it turns out that the main problem is (I think):

```
<qm:expanded-tree-cache-hits>17</qm:expanded-tree-cache-hits>
<qm:expanded-tree-cache-misses>9571</qm:expanded-tree-cache-misses>
<qm:compressed-tree-cache-hits>1</qm:compressed-tree-cache-hits>
<qm:compressed-tree-cache-misses>9570</qm:compressed-tree-cache-misses>
<qm:in-memory-compressed-tree-hits>0</qm:in-memory-compressed-tree-hits>
```

So it turns out that most SGDTEKST root element nodes are not indexed. Adding xdmp:query-meters() to count() for the other rootelements shows no cache misses (which is not surprising given the speed).

Why are some documents skipped? The size of the documents doesn't really differ (SGDTEKST is slightly bigger). The order of ingestion was to alternate, so it is not like the SGDTEKST documents were added last.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? And do I need to set an explicit index somewhere to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most caches, its behavior is based on usage. There's not much you can do to control it, other than run a script that warms it up with the documents you want in there. However, at some point it will start paging them out - that's just the nature of a cache.

If the elements you want to count are all roots of database documents, then you can simply use `xdmp:estimate(//element-name)`, which counts using indexes only, and will be much faster. `xdmp:estimate` will return the number of database documents that match the expression - if you know the expression to be one-to-one with a document, then `count()` and `xdmp:estimate()` should be equal.

Answer (score 3):

A cache miss does not mean "not indexed". MarkLogic indexes all elements by default.

Instead it means the entry wasn't in cache until the query loaded it. The cache is likely to be much smaller than the database, so only the [least recently used entries are cached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms). In this case the entries are trees: that is, documents.